# blazor not changing the page when clicking on a link

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I am migrating my personal blog to Blazor, and I have a problem. I was developing the "next post" functionality and blazor (or the browser) is not redirecting the user when a link is clicked. the post are "the same page" under the next route `@page "/post/{Url}`

For example the user is in `domain.com/post/foo` and in that site there is a link to `domain.com/post/bar`.
It is a simple link, like the next:

```
<a href="post/bar" title="@Post.Title">
    @Post.Title 
</a>
```

When the user clicks on the link the url for the browser changes, and the location of the page moves to the top, but the page content is not changing.

I noticed that this behaviour is happening when I click from a `post` page into another, but is not happening from the "index" of the site (`/`) or when I click the tags on the post, which links to `domain.com/tags/{tag}`.

one thing to notice is that if I select the url in the browser and click enter or refresh the page it actually goes to the page i clicked on, in this case `domain.com/post/bar`

My question is, is this actually expected behavior or is it a bug? if it is expected behaviour, is there any way of making the url to actually go to the clicked url and not stay in the same page.

I am using net5.0 if that matters.

Thanks.

Comment: Neither expected nor  a bug. There's a third possibility.

Comment: Why don't you share some code for a specific link that doesn't work.  Basically if it's not navigating it doesn't recognise the route.  In your example it doesn't know about `post/bar`.  When you say it isn't navigating when you click on the link, exactly what is happening?  Nothing, page refreshing,....  We need some clues.  Bug? are you doing something no one else is doing?

Comment: @ShaunCurtis the code is exactly that, changing `bar` for `@post/url` which translates into `bar`; the exact same code works in the index of the site. I would share more code, but I have no clue what to sahre.

When i click on the lilnk, the URL changes, and the scroll goes to the top. But the content itself does not change.

Comment: OK.  Some Questions.  On the page with the link you show what is the (at)page url?  On the page you are expecting to load with the url post/bar what's the (at)page url.  When you click on the link does the page refresh - watch the browser tab for the spinner?  Temporary publish to a Github Repo?

Comment: @ShaunCurtis so my current page is `http://localhost:44310/post/title1` and from that one I tried to access `http://localhost:44310/post/title2`being the link the one avobe (`href="post/@post.url"`).

So when I click on the link the url actually changes from title1 to  `http://localhost:44310/post/title2` but no spinner or anything.

also i checked with the f12 and console/network nothing in there either.

I cant really share a working version (passwords and crap hardcoded) so I am not sure if it is worth it to cleanup

Comment: @ShaunCurtis this is all the code in that razor component (is the child of a bigger one)

sorry for being into an image.
https://i.imgur.com/xEvuIKR.png

Edit: on initializedAsync is getting the "nextPost" information from the  backend, but its just a plain http call

Comment: You haven't told me what your @page references are.  I suspect the router believes `/post/title1` and `/post/title2` are the same page, so routes to self.  If you don't change any Parameters then there's nothing to update.  Is title1 and title2 a Parameter that you should be capturing?  [at]post/{title}?

Comment: @ShaunCurtis sorry i did misunderstood you, yes the route is tihs one `@page "/post/{Url}`I am capturing the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I click from a `post` page into another

`post` in `domain.com/post/foo` and `domain.com/post/bar` is definitely not a page but a literal path segment.

I've created a routable component named Foo:

### Foo.razor

```
@page "/post/foo"

@code {
}
```

Foo is a routable component; that is, it is a page, and can be accessed by typing the url in the address bar of your browser, using an anchor element or the NavigationManager. You may embed it in a parent component as well.

`post` is, as I've said above, a literal path segment

But if you insist that post is actually a component page, then I guess it may look something like this:

### Post.razor

```
@page "/post"
@page "/post/{Param}"
<a href="post/bar" title="Title">
Title 
</a>

<div>@Param</div>
@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Param {get;set;}
}
```

Now, when you type in the address bar a url like this:
`https://localhost:<port-number>/post`

You'll be navigated to the post routable component (page)

If you click on the anchor element, the url in the address bar will change to `https://localhost:<port-number>/post/bar`

`bar` is not a component; it is a parameter. The address bar changes, but you seem to be in the same post component, the data or content, however, do changes...

Note that when you click on the anchor element, you are being navigated to
a new Url ("post/bar"), but rendering engine does not create a new instance of the Post component in order to render the page, but instead it treats it as the same page with changed parameters. Thus it looks like no navigation has taken place, and nothing has changed, except the url in the address bar. I'm not claiming that your issue is the same, but it may stem from similar code usage.
Note that since Blazor does not create a new component instance, but uses the existing one, the OnInitialized(Async) pairs can only run once... So you'll have to use the SetParametersAsync method (" on initializedAsync is getting the "nextPost" information from the backend, but its just a plain http cal")

All the above was intended to ask you to do the simplest thing and provide the route templates........

Is bar a component?
Is foo a component?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, yes i do the template for the posts with ` @page "/post/{Param}" ` so defenilty the issue is the component is not being re-render.

I just tested with SetParametersAsync and seems to be working, I have to do it in all the child elements, but seems the way to go, thanks.

Comment: @TigreX as I suspected, see my add on answer below that crossed in the post with your comment here.  [thumbs up]

Answer (score 1):

As an add on to @enet's answer, you're probably fetching the post referenced by the `Url` property in `OnInitialized`/`OnInitializedAsync`.  See the last long paragraph in @enet's answer.

One way to address this is:

- place the code to load data in a separate method say `LoadDataAsync`
- in `SetParameters`/`SetParametersAsync` detect if the data reference - in your case `Url` - has changed in ,  and if so call `LoadDataAsync`.

The key here is understand component lifecycle and getting the code in the right place.

Put breakpoints in on `OnInitialized` and `SetParameters` and watch when they get hit when you load and do navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Answer withdrawn as it breaks some component parameter recommendations by ASPNetCore Team - see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24599

Comment: you shouldn't mutate the state of a parameter. You may read the value of a parameter property, but not change its value. Treat parameter properties as automatic properties, so said Steve Anderson.

Comment: read this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24599#issuecomment-697588562

Comment: The setter is a pretty standard, it's what I'm doing in the pseudo-event triggered by the setter - causing a re-render. The following section from the notes is pertinent - *The problem only occurs because setting the parameter values in the repro case does have side-effects which include triggering another re-render on the parent. The solution therefore is to leave the parameter communication channel alone (i.e., don't write to the properties, nor put in set logic that has side-effects).*  My solution has side-effects!  I've edited the answer to withdraw it but leave the edit/comment trail.

Comment: not sure if you need to remove your answer. My comment was only in reference to the fact that your code mutate a parameter property, and that you should avoid this practice... I did not really inspected your code, but if everything is fine, then you can define a local variable that gets the value of the parameter property, and then you may manipulate and mutate this variable as you like...

Comment: I am on the Parameter Property Setter version - I've delved deeper into the Renderer code.   It's the possible side-effects if you don't fully understand what you're doing.  While I'm happy to run it in my code and "understand" the consequences of my actions, I'm not going to recommend it to all.